# Page is not load if Facebook banned from network

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Our website is using Facebook login and normal login.

Facebook is banned on our university's network. When I try to enter our website at school, it's not loading. In network tab of Chrome, it's saying "pending...".

Edit after comments:

- Facebook SDK is already async. But not working like async.
- There is no javascript errors.
- Not trying to login with Facebook. Just trying to enter a website which one includes Facebook jssdk
- "Say it to your administration to fix it" is not a reply or solution. You know Facebook is blocked in China too. If it is behaving like this at there too, it's really bad thing.

Comment: You should edit your question to be more specific, because at first glance it kind of sounds like you just want to use facebook at school

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Facebook is blocked, therefore you can't use Facebook to authenticate.

Comment: This action by your school network administrators will cause similar issues for many mainstream sites as well. Tell your network administrators to fix it.

Comment: edited question after comments...

Comment: @xecute I've seen similar issues on a site I've worked on, though only while I had the "Facebook Disconnect" extension enabled.. are you also using this extension? If so, does disabling the extension fix the behavior? If you aren't using the extension, can you reproduce the behavior on a different network (one that allows FB) with a browser that has the FB Disconnect extension enabled?

Comment: Two things: 
1. Have you tried watching the network communication from developer console/firebug?
2. Are you using your laptop to go between the two networks, or is this a situation where you are using a school computer to access the site?

Comment: Could you post the URL to the page?

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to load the facebook SDK and tell us where it is added in the HTML? (head, body, end of body, middle of body...)

Answer (score 6):

> "Say it to your administration to fix it" is not a reply or solution.

Yes, it is.

From your problem description,

> When I try to enter our website at school, it's not loading. In network tab of Chrome, it's saying "pending..."

it sounds a lot like the request is blocked in a way that it is timing out – and so a whole website that has the SDK embedded is blocked from rendering … which can happen if the script is embedded in the `<head>` of the document.

So it *would be* in your admins’ power (and responsibility, one could argue) to fix that. In a way that does not let the request time out, but f.e. “redirects” it to a local web server, that can answer with a 403 Forbidden or 404 File Not Found etc. straight away, so that the browser does not wait (seemingly) endlessly for the download of a script resource that is never gonna happen.

> You know Facebook is blocked in China too. If it is behaving like this at there too, it's really bad thing.

Well, if that’s all the problems they have, lucky them … and I think I remember reading that Facebook isn’t even that popular there, but they have their “own” local social network instead …

Comment: Unless what he's really trying to do is climb over the great firewall and just keep it on the down low so the CCP doesn't find him out^^

Comment: A response with `403: Response Forbidden` would seem the right thing to do for the network administrator here.

Comment: This is not the answer and I don't know why people still upvoting this. We are not talking about reaching to Facebook here. We are talking about reaching to a website which one including Facebook's login and like box etc. JS. So, China's own social network is not point here. And it's not about admin too. He can do whatever he want(as like as you said with "one could argue").

Answer (score 1):

This question reminds me of a talk by Steve Sauders. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHDNmTpqi7w

He points out a few async links which may look like async but dont necessarily be async. Take a look at this and re examine your html. Hope this helps you to resolve the issue